# Local Service User Logged into Windows

Tags: windows-vista, service, windows-services

I created a Windows Service that Tracks which App Server a user is actually connected to through a load balancer.

It retrieves the user that is logged into windows on that machine, then cross references the Active Directory (AD) account to return the first name, last name and E-mail (for notification through the website created for this project)

There is one system on the Network where users only remote into the system, the Vista System, for some reason it is returning with Values that say "LOCAL SERVICE" is Logged into that machine, it's weird and the Security Guys say that it is impossible for the "LOCAL SERVICE" account to be logged into Windows.

Here is how I get the user that is logged into Windows

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from win32_computersystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, query);

foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    _username = mo["username"].ToString();
}
// remove the domain part from the username
string[] usernameParts = _username.Split('\\');
_username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];
```

is this an Edge Case that I can fix, or is the user actually "logged in" to this machine

Is there multiple users logged into this machine and Vista lists "LOCAL SERVICE" as one of them?

[Cross Post on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68076/18427)